# cURL code in PHP dumps output to the page

Tags: php, curl

How do I hide the output from curl in PHP?

My code as it stands is the following:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $pass);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

The problem is that is spews out the entire page to the user. Instead I want to capture the output and simply show a "success" or "failed" message?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Use this option to [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

This will make `curl_exec` return the data instead of outputting it.

To see if it was successful you can then check `$result` and also [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/curl_error).

Comment: I've read from http://stackoverflow.com/a/18203696/2495584 that it uses 1 as the second paramater. Which is the better one to use?

Comment: 0/False and 1/True are interchangeable as boolean data types. So, it's exactly the same thing, take your pick.

Answer (score 16):

**Also make sure to turn off this option:**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
```

Or else it will still print everything to screen.

Comment: `else it will still print everything to screen` - no it won't, CURLOPT_VERBOSE is 0 by default, and always has been.