# echoing variable works, but not putting inside a file?

Tags: php, variables

I have a variable called `$filter`. If I run `echo $filter;` I get the contents of it. However, If I run

```
file_put_contents("/nrj/vvr/tmp/lol", $filter);
```

I do get the file, but the contents is just `1`. It should contain alot of different things. I use the exact same syntax usually, and it works. I get no error messages.

Comment: not getting error messages.. ok. Well, is your system setup "to" catch/log/display?

Comment: whats the content of `$filter`?

Comment: and a path like this `"/nrj/vvr/tmp/lol"` implies in wanting to use a system path `"/var/usr/public/nrj/vvr/tmp/lol"` and with a trailing slash perhaps after `lol` -  `"/var/usr/public/nrj/vvr/tmp/lol/"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, I get messages about some function in a file I don't use anymore being outdated, just no messages related to that.

Comment: @Flosculus a html file.

Comment: Have you tried writing to any other file?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tried it with different paths, the output is still `1` :/.

Comment: we need to see what `$filter` is assigned as/coming from. probably a boolean somewhere rather than the intended string, if it's a string.

Comment: well, at this point and not seeing any "answers" below, I think it'll be a while till you do see one. I am moving on, good luck *sincerely*.

Comment: Do you do `if ($filter = 1)` prior to this?

Comment: @chris85 I tried that, and it did say it's value was `1`, but that's very strange since I echo it literally the line above and I get my desired value.

Comment: That isn't a comparison; that sets/overrides the value. That's the only reason I would see this being 1 (or one of the only reasons). Show more code, such as where you output it or where you set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was the problem

```
$filter = curl_exec($ch);
```

For some reason, it ignores the first things and just executes it without setting any variable. Under this I had

```
echo $filter;
```

Giving me the impression that it was that line that output it, but it was the one above.

Comment: So this is resolved or you need to get the CURL response to the variable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203411/save-curl-display-output-string-in-variable-php

Comment: @chris85 I have solved the issue in another way, but I had this already set in my code `curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`.