# Don't show logs with PHP command and cURL

Tags: php, api, curl, console

I developed a script with PHP which I use with the console, with the command `php index.php`.

In this script, I use cURL to query a server.

The problem is my script shows logs on the console, and I just want the result of the echo.

Do you have an idea to hide these logs?

```
// GET TOKEN
// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "some/url";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pwd");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$location = "";
preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $data, $location);
$location = trim($location[1][0]);
$location = parse_url($location);
parse_str($location['query'], $attrs);
$token = $attrs['code'];

if( isset($token) ) {

    // GET CONNEXION
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $url = "some/url";
    $post_data = ['code' => $token, 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$client_id:$client_secret");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    $connexion = isset($data->access_token) ? $data->access_token : $data->error_description;

    // GET LOGIN
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $url = "some/url";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    // $login = json_encode(['public' => $data->api_keys[1]->public, 'secret' => $data->api_keys->secret]);

    // REQUEST
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $url = $request . "?externalId=".$external_id."&externalSource=".$external_source;
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
    $nonce = generateRandomString();
    file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r("Set random nonce to " . $nonce . "\n", TRUE));
    $created = date("Y-m-dTH:i:sP");
    $created = date("Y-m-dTH:i:sP");
    $username = $data->api->public;
    $secret = $data->api->secret;
    $pwd_digest = base64_encode(sha1($nonce.$created.$secret));
    $auth_header = "X-WSSE: UsernameToken Username=\"$username\", PasswordDigest=\"$pwd_digest\", Nonce=\"$nonce\", Created=\"$created\"";
    $header = array($auth_header, 'Accept: something', 'Accept-Language: en');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    echo $data->nbNqPoints;

} else {
    echo "0";
}
```

Comment: Because with each site we must process with each way. So can you provide your $url and any thing you can provide so we can help you!

Comment: I don't know if it is related or not, but where you set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, try setting it to `true` instead of 1.

Comment: you could use a little ob_start(); ob_get_clean(); hack to get through it

Comment: Thanks, @BrandonHorsley, but it doesn't change anything! ;)

Comment: Very interesting @hanshenrik! I try this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found at this address: [managing curl output in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234537/managing-curl-output-in-php)

I add this line for every cURL instance :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
```